# How to write various inputs into the same file in different containers from the same Docker image?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, containers, command-line-arguments

i have an docker image and this image creates containers which has abc.txt
i want this abc.txt in different containers with different inputs;
ie:
in container1

> abc.txt

```
www.youtube.com
```

in container2

> abc.txt

```
www.twitter.com
```

how can i have containers like this? i guess i should use entrypoint and pass arguments. i want to give file input myself when docker run as an argument
(in centos)

Comment: You can mount a file from the host into the container under this name using the -v option of docker run. To specify it as an argument you will need to wrap this into a small shell script.

Comment: can you please show me an example for the script? thank you

Answer (score 0):

A simple script (assuming you are on linux) could look like this:

```
#! /bin/bash

docker run -v "$1":/abc.txt yourimage
```

If you call it with a file as argument this will be mounted into the container as `/abc.txt`.

Comment: should i call this script on dockerfile? 7or should i run containers with this script?

Comment: It would be used to start a container